# get_rate_status "remaining hits" does not decrease when I make GET calls anymore

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a script written to iterate through a list of Twitter userIDs and save the lists of follower_ids to a file. I have used it several times with no problems. For long lists, I have added this piece of code to check the rate limit before every GET request and sleep if I'm about to be rate-limited:

```
rate_limit_json = api.rate_limit_status()
 remaining_hits = rate_limit_json["remaining_hits"]
 print 'you have', remaining_hits, 'API calls remaining until next hour'
 if remaining_hits < 2:
      dtcode = datetime.utcnow()
      unixtime = calendar.timegm(dtcode.utctimetuple())
      sleeptime = rate_limit_json['reset_time_in_seconds'] - unixtime + 10
      print 'waiting ', sleeptime, 'seconds'
      time.sleep(sleeptime)
 else:
      pass
```

I have this Oauth blurb set up at the top of the script:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxx', 'xxxx')
auth.set_access_token('xxxx', 'xxxxx')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

The call I'm repeatedly making is:

```
follower_cursors = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids)
```

So now, no matter how many calls I make, my "remaining hits" stays at 150 until Twitter returns a "Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 350 requests per hour."

It seems like the rate limit checker is reporting my unauthorized, IP address's rate limit (150), but my calls are counting against my app's rate limit (350).

How can I adjust my rate limit checker to actually check the app's rate limit again?

Answer (score 0):

Repeated creating a `Cursor` instance doesn't use up any API quote, as it doesn't actually make a request to twitter. A `Cursor` is just a Tweepy wrapper around different pagination methods. Calling the `next` or `prev` methods, of iterating over it, cause actual API calls.

Twitter no longer has a concept of unauthenticated API calls (the v1.1 API always requires authentication). I think the problem lies with your use of `Cursor`. Try creating just once instance, and calling the `next` method repeatedly (make sure to catch a `StopIteration` exception, as `next` is a generator).